# How to handle Configure file Windows-8

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, visual-c++-2010

i have a configure file named "Example.CFG" in which arguments for main function are mentioned. When i run the code in visual studio 2013, it runs successfully, but configuration file does not supply any arguments to main and each time execute the else portion. By googling I know the reason as . /Configure only works in Linux. My problem is that how to by pass the configure file and supply arguments directly to main . My code is below  (The code is not mine but downloaded from Github)

```
int main(int argc, void** argv) {
tricrf::MaxEnt *model;
vector<string> model_file, train_file, dev_file, test_file, output_file;
string initialize_method, estimation_method;
size_t max_iter, init_iter;
double l1_prior, l2_prior;
enum {MaxEnt = 0, CRF, TriCRF1, TriCRF2, TriCRF3} model_type;
bool train_mode = false, testing_mode = false;
bool confidence = false;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///  Reading the configuration file
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
char config_filename[128];
if (argc > 1) {
strcpy_s(config_filename, (char*)argv[1]);
}
else {
cout << MAX_HEADER;
cout << "[Usage] max config_file \n\n";
exit(1);        
}
```

My Configur file having the following entries:

```
# sample configuration file
model_type = TriCRF3 
# {MaxEnt CRF TriCRF1 TriCRF2 TriCRF3}
mode = both 
# {train test both}
train_file = example.data
test_file = example.data
model_file = example.model
cutoff = 1 
# feature cutoff by count
true_label = first 
# if 'first' is on, it reads first columns as true labels
outside_label = NONE 
# it would be used for F1 calculation
binary_model = false 
# currently, not support
estimation = LBFGS-L2 
# {LBFGS-L1 LBFGS-L2}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?